# Date as number in sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, date-arithmetic

When we type current date in Excel cell as 08-May-2013
Right click on the cell and in the format when i click number as category i get a number

```
    Date-08-May-13
    Formatted one-41402.00
```

So is there anyway i can get the same number in sql

I tried using this.

```
    select to_char(sysdate,'J') from dual
```

But the output is 2456421

I understand that this is a Julian value

But can anyone help me in getting the output as that i am getting on excel i.e; 41402

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows version of Excel stores dates as serial numbers. 01-Jan-1900 is 1, 02-Jan-1900 is 2, etc.  The Mac version used to use a different starting date; I don't know whether that's still the case.

The essential data you need is in simple date arithmetic.

```
select current_date, current_date - date '1900-01-01'
from dual;
```

That returns 41400.67037037037 for my current connection. Rounding up and adding 1 for fenceposting would return the number you're looking for, but I'd want to test that with multiple time zones and such before I'd swear by it.

Answer (score 5):

A date in Excel is stored as a serial number, with 01-JAN-1900 as 1.  [Citation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/datevalue-HP005209044.aspx).

We can do arithmetic with dates in Oracle, so converting to an Excel date from Oracle would be:

```
trunc(sysdate) - to_date( '1900-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

I've tested this and infuriatingly it produces 41401 - because it's going from midnight.  So obviously Microsoft are using a ceiling function to raise it to the next integer:

```
ceil (sysdate - to_date( '1900-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') )
```